# Calculating ratio between rows using ArcPy module

Tags: arcpy

I want to calculate the ratio between the rows (i.e., row1/row2, row2/row3 and so on..) of the 'Frequency' column based on the 'Id' column and want to assign the values to a separate column. As expected there will be no ratio for the 1st row. Here is my data-

```
OID Id  Frequency
0   1   50680
1   2   49740
2   3   48620
3   4   48300
4   5   48004
5   6   45600
6   7   44384
7   8   42720
8   9   41890
9   10  39700
10  11  38530
11  12  38207
12  13  38106
13  14  37303
14  15  37205
15  16  36527
16  17  35301
17  18  31674
18  19  28890
19  20  24612
```

Comment: Not sure, Maybe with SearchCursor() ;)

Comment: Look at the sample code on the help file and pay special attention to the use of global statement outside the coffee block.

Comment: Please edit the original question rather than this one, or edit both to make it clear that one is asking about how to do it in the field calculator, and the other how to do it using ArcPy.  Whenever you ask a coding question make sure to include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: The way I would approach this is using a SearchCursor to load a dictionary with all values, and then use an UpdateCursor to process each row while reading the previous row's value from the dictionary.